# GWT RPC call gets repeated after 30 seconds

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-rpc

I am experiencing a weird problem in a GWT application. I have multiple RPC calls which work correctly, however if one of them takes longer than 30 seconds on the server side (for example a database or web service call took a long time), the server side code gets repeated (literally; the code get executed again).

I do not experience this in my develompent environment, however when I deploy the application (container is Jetty 6.1.24 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS) and connect to it from a browser (regardless of the type), the problem starts to exist.

Since I do not think this a designed GWT behaviour (but I might be wrong ofcourse) I am basically looking for ways to debug this and find out the reason for it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Some more information would be great to understand what is going on, but I would start the investigation by first narrowing down whether the erroneous GWT-RPC call is triggered on the client or server.

To see if the extra GWT-RPC request originates from the browser, in Google Chrome, go to View->Developer->Developer Tools.. Click on the Network Tab.

As you reproduce your steps, the Network Tab will show you every request sent to the server.

If you see the erroneous GWT-RPC request logged in this Network Tab View, then the request is fired off from the GWT-compiled Javascript in the application. With SuperDevMode, you can then set debug breakpoints in the browser and see what is triggering the request.

If the erroneous GWT-RPC is not shown in the Network Tab View, then the server-side method is somehow triggered by your server code/configuration. Set some debug breakpoints on your server code, and drill down the call stack to see what is calling the method.

Hope that helps to get started on the investigation.